# How to remove iframe src on outside click of bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a project which has a bootstrap modal to play a video. When the user clicks outside of the modal, the model closes but the video keeps playing in the background. How to add an event to remove the `iframe` `src` on clicking on the outside of the modal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener for when the modal closes for any reason.
Try the following:

```
$('#yourModalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { // runs every time the modal is hidden
  $('#iframeId').attr('src', ''); // clears src attribute
})
```